# EPICOR - Eable a tab

Tags: epicor

Is there a way to enable a tab, that is disabled by default, using a customization or a BPM?

For instance, if you go to Sales Management/Demand Management/Setup/Part, and you create a new part, some tabs are disabled. I want enable them using a C# code, and enter default values.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons all the controls on a particular tab could be disabled.

There could be a RowRule that disables them, for example, if you don't have "Track Lots" checked on the front screen then the Part>Lots>Attributes and Part>Lots>Generate tabs will be disabled.

The tab could be for a row that hasn't been added yet, for example, everything on Part>Revisions>Detail will be disabled for a new part until you choose File>New...>New Part Revision.

There are also many parts of the system that require a specific license, for example, Integrations>External CRM requires extra licences, you would need to contact your account manager to arrange their purchase.

Epicor support or an Epicor consult should be able to tell you the reason, in any case, just enabling them in a c# customisation will not make the business logic behind them work.